# How to make plugin manager in notepad++ 32bit?

Tags: notepad++

I installed 'notepad++' a few months ago and left it unused.(32bit)
And I started using 'notepad++' for the first time today.

While using it, I noticed that the plugin manager can not output plugins that can be installed.

For that reason, I deleted 'notepad++' and reinstalled it.(32bit)
Then the 'plugin manager' button did not exist.

For solving this problem, I searched.
But I couldn't find anything.

If you experienced same problem and solved this problem, please help me.

I use window7 64bit.

Comment: This is being discussed on the Notepad++ forums. See https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/# and the reason is given at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5-released.html

Comment: This means that will the plugin manager be supported again in later updates? @AdrianHHH